# How to write union all in linq for two linq results

Tags: c#, linq

```
var data11 = (from p in db.FeePlan.Where(d => d.AcademicYearID == dts.AcademicYearID && d.Active == true && d.IsEffectiveDates == false)
              from fb in db.FeePlansToBranches.Where(x => x.FeePlanID == p.FeePlanID && x.BranchID == BranchID)
              from b in db.Branches.Where(b => b.BranchID == fb.BranchID)
              from fp in db.AssignFeeplanToClasses.Where(a => a.BranchID == BranchID && a.ClassID == ClassID && a.FeePlanID == p.FeePlanID)
              from cl in db.Classes.Where(c => c.ClassID == fp.ClassID)
              select new
                     {
                         p.FeePlanName,
                         p.FeePlanID,
                         b.BranchName,
                         cl.ClassName,
                         fp.AssignFeeplanToClassID,
                         fp.CreatedDate
                     }).Distinct().ToList();

var data2 = (from p in db.FeePlan.Where(d => d.AcademicYearID == dts.AcademicYearID && d.Active == true &&d.IsEffectiveDates == true)
             from fb in db.FeePlansToBranches.Where(x => x.FeePlanID == p.FeePlanID && x.BranchID == BranchID)
             from b in db.Branches.Where(b => b.BranchID == fb.BranchID)
             from fp in db.AssignFeeplanToClasses.Where(a => a.BranchID == BranchID && a.ClassID == ClassID && a.FeePlanID == p.FeePlanID)
             from cl in db.Classes.Where(c => c.ClassID == fp.ClassID)
             where (DateTime.Now> p.StartDate && DateTime.Now < p.EndDate)
             select new
                    {
                        p.FeePlanName,
                        p.FeePlanID,
                        cl.ClassName,
                        b.BranchName,
                        fp.AssignFeeplanToClassID,
                        fp.CreatedDate
                    }).Distinct().ToList();

js.Data = data11.Union(data2);
```

I am new to linq; please help me how to use union all in linq query for two variable stores the result.

In the above code I am using two linq queries to get results, but I want to union the two results stored in other variables. Please help me.

Comment: you can use [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of UNION ALL in Linq is `Concat`.

`js.Data = data11.Concat(data2);`

See http://theburningmonk.com/2010/02/linq-choosing-between-concat-and-union/ .

Answer (score 1):

As you are converting both collection to list you can use [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) Method of List to do this.

```
  var data11 = (from p in db.FeePlan.Where(d => d.AcademicYearID == dts.AcademicYearID && d.Active == true && d.IsEffectiveDates == false)
                          from fb in db.FeePlansToBranches.Where(x => x.FeePlanID == p.FeePlanID && x.BranchID == BranchID)
                          from b in db.Branches.Where(b => b.BranchID == fb.BranchID)
                          from fp in db.AssignFeeplanToClasses.Where(a => a.BranchID == BranchID && a.ClassID == ClassID && a.FeePlanID == p.FeePlanID)
                          from cl in db.Classes.Where(c => c.ClassID == fp.ClassID)
                          select new
                          {
                              p.FeePlanName,
                              p.FeePlanID,
                              b.BranchName,
                              cl.ClassName,
                              fp.AssignFeeplanToClassID,
                              fp.CreatedDate
                          }).Distinct().ToList().AddRange(

            (from p in db.FeePlan.Where(d => d.AcademicYearID == dts.AcademicYearID && d.Active == true &&d.IsEffectiveDates == true)
                         from fb in db.FeePlansToBranches.Where(x => x.FeePlanID == p.FeePlanID && x.BranchID == BranchID)
                         from b in db.Branches.Where(b => b.BranchID == fb.BranchID)
                         from fp in db.AssignFeeplanToClasses.Where(a => a.BranchID == BranchID && a.ClassID == ClassID && a.FeePlanID == p.FeePlanID)
                         from cl in db.Classes.Where(c => c.ClassID == fp.ClassID)
                         where (DateTime.Now> p.StartDate && DateTime.Now < p.EndDate)
                         select new
                         {
                             p.FeePlanName,
                             p.FeePlanID,
                             cl.ClassName,
                             b.BranchName,
                             fp.AssignFeeplanToClassID,
                             fp.CreatedDate
                         }).Distinct().ToList());
```

Comment: If you want to go the linq way you can use @mjwills method

Comment: You may even be able to remove the final .ToList() call since AddRange takes an IEnumerable - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx .

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

```
var data3 = data11.Concat(data2).ToList();
```

Or

```
var data3 = new List<object>(data1);
data3.AddRange(data2);
```

But since you seem to not want duplicates, you may still want to use `union`:

```
var data3 = data11.Union(data2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var data11 = (from p in db.FeePlan.Where(d => d.AcademicYearID == dts.AcademicYearID && d.Active == true && d.IsEffectiveDates == false)
                              from fb in db.FeePlansToBranches.Where(x => x.FeePlanID == p.FeePlanID && x.BranchID == BranchID)
                              from b in db.Branches.Where(b => b.BranchID == fb.BranchID)
                              from fp in db.AssignFeeplanToClasses.Where(a => a.BranchID == BranchID && a.ClassID == ClassID && a.FeePlanID == p.FeePlanID)
                              from cl in db.Classes.Where(c => c.ClassID == fp.ClassID)
                              select new
                              {
                                  FeePlanName = p.FeePlanName,
                                  FeePlanID = p.FeePlanID,
                                  ClassName = cl.ClassName,
                                  BranchName = b.BranchName,
                                  AssignFeeplanToClassID = fp.AssignFeeplanToClassID,
                                  CreatedDate = fp.CreatedDate
                              }).ToList();

                var data2 = (from p in db.FeePlan.Where(d => d.AcademicYearID == dts.AcademicYearID && d.Active == true && d.IsEffectiveDates == true)
                             from fb in db.FeePlansToBranches.Where(x => x.FeePlanID == p.FeePlanID && x.BranchID == BranchID)
                             from b in db.Branches.Where(b => b.BranchID == fb.BranchID)
                             from fp in db.AssignFeeplanToClasses.Where(a => a.BranchID == BranchID && a.ClassID == ClassID && a.FeePlanID == p.FeePlanID)
                             from cl in db.Classes.Where(c => c.ClassID == fp.ClassID)
                             where (DateTime.Now > p.StartDate && DateTime.Now < p.EndDate)
                             select new
                             {
                            FeePlanName=   p.FeePlanName,
                              FeePlanID=   p.FeePlanID,
                               ClassName=  cl.ClassName,
                             BranchName=    b.BranchName,
                                AssignFeeplanToClassID= fp.AssignFeeplanToClassID,
                                CreatedDate= fp.CreatedDate
                             }).ToList();

                js.Data = data11.Concat(data2);
```

Comment: I believe your removal of the Distinct() calls may cause you issues (i.e. duplicates), assuming you had them before on purpose.

Comment: You will probably find you could remove both ToList() calls as well.